# Pandas: Aggregate rows based on index labels vs. columns labels condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (400,328) dataframe which structure looks like this:

```
row_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['EU', 'ROW'],
                             ['p01.a', 'p01.b', 'p02.1.a', 'p02.1.b', 'p02.1.c', 'p03']],
                            names=['Region', 'Prod_code'])

col_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['EU', 'ROW'],
                             ['i01.a', 'i01.b', 'i02.1.a', 'i03']],
                            names=['Region', 'Ind_code'])


df_in = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(12,8)), index=row_idx, columns=col_idx)

print(df)

Region              EU                     ROW                  
Ind_code         i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03
Region Prod_code                                                
EU     p01.a         1     9       7   4     2     1       6   7
       p01.b         1     5       1   7     2     4       2   2
       p02.1.a       1     1       2   8     8     4       4   7
       p02.1.b       7     7       7   5     6     7       1   3
       p02.1.c       4     2       4   4     6     4       3   8
       p03           7     2       9   8     8     8       4   3
ROW    p01.a         4     4       5   5     5     1       6   2
       p01.b         5     2       3   4     9     4       9   6
       p02.1.a       4     4       8   8     4     7       6   6
       p02.1.b       7     9       3   2     1     5       4   1
       p02.1.c       4     2       1   2     9     8       8   5
       p03           6     7       6   6     6     9       7   5
```

I need to obtain a symmetric Dataframe (328,328) by summing all rows for which the respective Prod_code has no correspondence to Ind_code (ignoring the initial letters "i" and "p"). The "extra" rows - in this case ('..', 'p02.1.b') and ('..', 'p02.1.c') - should be summed to the first row with a corresponded parent code - in this case ('..', 'p02.1.a'), like below.

```
#Desired output
print(df_out)

Region              EU                     ROW                  
Ind_code         i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03
Region Prod_code                                                
EU     p01.a         1     9       7   4     2     1       6   7
       p01.b         1     5       1   7     2     4       2   2
       p02.1.a      12    11      13  17    20    15       8  18
       p03           7     2       9   8     8     8       4   3
ROW    p01.a         4     4       5   5     5     1       6   2
       p01.b         5     2       3   4     9     4       9   6
       p02.1.a      15    15      12  12    14    20      18  12
       p03           6     7       6   6     6     9       7   5
```

How can I do this in an elegant "Pythonic" way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other answer not preserving the multi-index, To preserve and calculate use:

```
print(df_in)
Region              EU                     ROW                  
Ind_code         i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 
Region Prod_code                                                          
EU     p01.a         5     9       6   3     4     7       7   3
       p01.b         9     6       4   6     9     2       6   4
       p02.1         7     1       4   6     4     2       7   4
       p02.1         7     3       3   8     1     6       6   8
       p02.1         2     4       7   8     9     5       5   3
       p03           7     7       6   3     5     7       8   1
ROW    p01.a         3     3       3   7     5     7       4   4
       p01.b         8     8       1   4     4     3       3   3
       p02.1         8     5       3   6     6     4       4   3
       p02.1         8     1       3   5     5     5       6   5
       p02.1         1     7       1   4     9     3       6   3
       p03           3     6       1   5     1     8       4   1
```

---

**OUTPUT :**

```
#getting level 1 values of multi-index
Prod_code = df_in.index.get_level_values(1)

#Assing these values to `Prod_code` column
df_in['Prod_code'] = Prod_code

#Setting the level 1 with values that contain duplicates
df_in.index.set_levels(Prod_code.str.slice(start=0,stop=5,step=1),
                       level=1,verify_integrity=False,inplace=True)

#Getting the values with only one duplicated value as per OP's condition
#Using groupby on level=0,1 of multi-index
level_0 = df_in.index.get_level_values(0)
level_1 = df_in.index.get_level_values(1)
valuestoset = df_in.groupby([level_0,level_1])['Prod_code'].first()

#Finding the sum on groupby object on level=0,1 of multi-index which contains duplicates
df_out = df_in.groupby([level_0,level_1]).sum()

#Finally setting the valuestoset to multi-index to preseve the order
df_out.index.set_levels(valuestoset,level=1,verify_integrity=False,inplace=True)
print(df_out)
Region              EU                     ROW                  
Ind_code         i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03
Region Prod_code                                                
EU     p01.a         5     9       6   3     4     7       7   3
       p01.b         9     6       4   6     9     2       6   4
       p02.1.a      16     8      14  22    14    13      18  15
       p03           7     7       6   3     5     7       8   1
ROW    p01.a         3     3       3   7     5     7       4   4
       p01.b         8     8       1   4     4     3       3   3
       p02.1.a      17    13       7  15    20    12      16  11
       p03           3     6       1   5     1     8       4   1
```

---

**Explanation :**

```
print(df_in.index.get_level_values(1))
Index(['p01.a', 'p01.b', 'p02.1.a', 'p02.1.b', 'p02.1.c', 'p03', 'p01.a',
       'p01.b', 'p02.1.a', 'p02.1.b', 'p02.1.c', 'p03'],
      dtype='object', name='Prod_code')


Prod_code = df_in.index.get_level_values(1)
df_in['Prod_code'] = index_col
df_in.index.set_levels(Prod_code.str.slice(start=0,stop=5,step=1),
                       level=1,verify_integrity=False,inplace=True)


print(df_in)
Region              EU                     ROW                   Prod_code
Ind_code         i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03          
Region Prod_code                                                          
EU     p01.a         5     9       6   3     4     7       7   3     p01.a
       p01.b         9     6       4   6     9     2       6   4     p01.b
       p02.1         7     1       4   6     4     2       7   4   p02.1.a
       p02.1         7     3       3   8     1     6       6   8   p02.1.b
       p02.1         2     4       7   8     9     5       5   3   p02.1.c
       p03           7     7       6   3     5     7       8   1       p03
ROW    p01.a         3     3       3   7     5     7       4   4     p01.a
       p01.b         8     8       1   4     4     3       3   3     p01.b
       p02.1         8     5       3   6     6     4       4   3   p02.1.a
       p02.1         8     1       3   5     5     5       6   5   p02.1.b
       p02.1         1     7       1   4     9     3       6   3   p02.1.c
       p03           3     6       1   5     1     8       4   1       p03
```

---

```
df_in.groupby([level_0,level_1])['Prod_code'].first()
Region  Prod_code
EU      p01.a          p01.a
        p01.b          p01.b
        p02.1        p02.1.a
        p03              p03
ROW     p01.a          p01.a
        p01.b          p01.b
        p02.1        p02.1.a
        p03              p03
Name: Prod_code, dtype: object

df_in.groupby([level_0,level_1]).sum()

Region              EU                     ROW                  
Ind_code         i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03
Region Prod_code                                                
EU     p01.a         5     9       6   3     4     7       7   3
       p01.b         9     6       4   6     9     2       6   4
       p02.1        16     8      14  22    14    13      18  15
       p03           7     7       6   3     5     7       8   1
ROW    p01.a         3     3       3   7     5     7       4   4
       p01.b         8     8       1   4     4     3       3   3
       p02.1        17    13       7  15    20    12      16  11
       p03           3     6       1   5     1     8       4   1
```

---

```
df_out.index.set_levels(valuestoset,level=1,verify_integrity=False,inplace=True)
Region              EU                     ROW                  
Ind_code         i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03 i01.a i01.b i02.1.a i03
Region Prod_code                                                
EU     p01.a         5     9       6   3     4     7       7   3
       p01.b         9     6       4   6     9     2       6   4
       p02.1.a      16     8      14  22    14    13      18  15
       p03           7     7       6   3     5     7       8   1
ROW    p01.a         3     3       3   7     5     7       4   4
       p01.b         8     8       1   4     4     3       3   3
       p02.1.a      17    13       7  15    20    12      16  11
       p03           3     6       1   5     1     8       4   1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try of grouping first Index level 0 and index level 1 with slice of 4 digits string and apply summation of dataframe values
df

```
        Region  EU  ROW
        Ind_code    i01.a   i01.b   i02.1.a i03 i01.a   i01.b   i02.1.a i03
Region  Prod_code                               
EU       p01.a       6  6   7   1   7   7   8   3
         p01.b       8  6   6   7   7   1   2   9
         p02.1.a     3  9   1   5   9   4   1   3
         p02.1.b     4  2   1   7   1   4   8   8
         p02.1.c     3  1   6   9   7   8   4   1
         p03         2  2   3   8   1   6   3   7
ROW      p01.a       8  4   9   7   7   9   1   6
         p01.b       7  8   3   3   7   9   7   3
         p02.1.a     7  3   4   5   7   7   7   4
         p02.1.b     5  5   6   7   7   2   9   7
         p02.1.c     4  8   7   5   3   7   7   8
         p03         3  3   3   9   9   6   3   8


# Assigning level 1 index to variable to keep the original Index
level1_index = df.index.get_level_values(0) + '_'+ df.index.get_level_values(1)
# Applying Groupby and extracting the first position index of every grouped rows
level1_index = list(map(lambda x: x[0].split('_')[1],level1_index.groupby(level1_index.str.slice(stop=9)).values()))
# Groupin the dataframe on level 0 and level 1 indexes 
df = df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),df.index.get_level_values(1).str.slice(stop=5)]).sum()
# Assigning level 1 index back to the dataframe 
df.index.set_levels(level1_index,level=1,verify_integrity=False,inplace=True)
```

Out:

```
        Region  EU  ROW
        Ind_code    i01.a   i01.b   i02.1.a i03 i01.a   i01.b   i02.1.a i03
Region  Prod_code                               
EU      p01.a   6   6   7   1   7   7   8   3
        p01.b   8   6   6   7   7   1   2   9
        p02.1.a 10  12  8   21  17  16  13  12
        p03 2   2   3   8   1   6   3   7
ROW     p01.a   8   4   9   7   7   9   1   6
        p01.b   7   8   3   3   7   9   7   3
        p02.1.a 16  16  17  17  17  16  23  19
        p03 3   3   3   9   9   6   3   8
```

Comment: Can I know what this line `df.index.get_level_values(1).str.slice(stop=5)` does?

Comment: Yes @Sai Kumar, it will take the 2nd level index(Region Ind...Prod_code) of multilevel index and slice the index to 5 values string .

Comment: @NagaKiran This does not preserve the multi-index as per OP's output.

Comment: I just edited , now it will provide the OP's output @SandeepKadapa , thanks for suggestion :-)